# Using a void function to calculate most frequent integer in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, element, counting

Hello! I am trying to create a program (school assignment) that asks the user to enter a sequence of integer numbers between 0 - 1000. The sequence stops when the user enters a negative integer or more than 100 integers.

Actually entering, saving and creating a "counter" array with the amount of times the integers have been entered is accomplished. However, a part of the assignment is creating a void function that uses pointer variables to return what integer occurred the most times and how many times it occurred.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SEQ 100

void analyzeFrequencies(int mainArray[], int counter[], int* mOI, int* numOfOccurences);

int main()
{
    int i=0, *mOI=0, *numOfOccurences=0, tempNum=0, mainArray[MAX_SEQ] = {0}, counter[MAX_SEQ] = {0};

    printf("Please enter a integer between 0-1000.\nSequence will stop when you enter negative integer of after MAX_SEQ integers.\n\n");

    do
    {
        if( scanf("%d", &tempNum) == 1)
        {
            if (tempNum <= 1000)
            {
                if (tempNum < 0)
                {
                    printf("You decided to exit the sequence. Your array entered is:\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    mainArray[i] = tempNum;
                    counter[tempNum]++;
                    ++i;
                }
            }
            else
                printf("Please enter a number between 0-1000. Exit sequence by entering negative number.\n");
        }
        else
            printf("\nError.\n");

    } while(tempNum > 0 && i < MAX_SEQ);

    analyzeFrequencies(mainArray, counter, mOI, numOfOccurences); //This is where the problem occurs.

    if (i == 0)
    {
        printf("You entered no sequence.");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nSequence:\n");
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
        {
            printf("[%d] %d\n", j, mainArray[j]);
        }

        printf("Most occurred item: %d\nOccurred %d times!", *mOI, *numOfOccurences);
    }
return 0;
}
```

When I run my code, everything works fine until I execute the analyzeFrequencies() function. The program then stops working.

```
void analyzeFrequencies(int mainArray[], int counter[], int* mOI, int* numOfOccurences)
{
    for(int i=0; i<MAX_SEQ; i++)
    {
        if(counter[i] > *numOfOccurences)
        {
            *mOI = i;
            *numOfOccurences = counter[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the function "void analyzeFrequencies" to return a pointer variable value through "mOI" and "numOfOccurences". mOI is the most occurred integer.

Instead, the program just stops working. I've been looking at my code for a while but can't seem to find what causes this. I might have been sitting for too long with my code and gone blind. Would appriciate any help to realize where I am going wrong!

P.S! I realize the code is not optimized at all and I would gladly receive any feedback, my main priority is however making the analyzeFrequencies function to start working!

Comment: "stops working" in what way? Does it crash? Hang?

Comment: @Steve An error appears (Windows 8) saying my .exe stopped working, then the command prompt terminates and gives me a weird return error. Sorry for being vague with my description. https://gyazo.com/da727575b1e6f61b9512fc3bb8e6c287

Comment: You should definitely lear how to use your debugger.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes, I agree. I am used to the Eclipse debugger but I recently swapped to CodeBlocks and so far it has only confused me. I'm still trying to learn how to use it properly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int i=0, *mOI=0, *numOfOccurences=0, tempNum=0, 
    mainArray[MAX_SEQ] = {0}, counter[MAX_SEQ] = {0};
```

In your `main` funciton, you have `mOI` and `numOfOccurences` declared as pointer variables, both of which are initialized to 0, meaning they are NULL pointers.  You then pass those NULL pointers into your function and dereference them.  Dereferencing a NULL pointer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Declare these two variables as `int` instead of `int *` and pass their **addresses** to `analyzeFrequencies`.

So declare them like this:

```
int i=0, mOI=0, numOfOccurences=0, tempNum=0, 
    mainArray[MAX_SEQ] = {0}, counter[MAX_SEQ] = {0};
```

And call your function like this:

```
analyzeFrequencies(mainArray, counter, &mOI, &numOfOccurences)
```

Comment: Wow! It worked. Would not assigning the pointers as NULL change anything or just cause more problems? Thank you so much!

Comment: @lemonslayer In that case you would be reading an uninitialized value which is also undefined behavior, and probably would have caused a crash.

Comment: Sorry but I just saw in my assignment the following: "The two computed values (number that occurs the most and number of occurances) should be taken as pointer variable arguments." Does this still apply with the changes you suggested?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding how this works .... `counter` is initialized with `MAX_SEQ` = 100 elements.  But the OP is indexing using the variable `tempNum` which ranges from 0 to 1000 (inclusive).  I think it's still broken.  `counter` should be allocated to have 1001 elements.

Comment: @lemonslayer Yes, it works the same.  Your function is still taking pointers for those two argument.  We just changed the values of the pointers passed in.

Comment: @MFisherKDX You're 100% correct, that was a mistake from my end, thank you for pointing that out I had completely missed it! The counter is supposed to have the same range as tempNum.

Comment: @dbush Ah, thank you so much! You have saved me, I probably need to read about pointers a bit more to fully understand how they work!